# How write dockerfile to properly pull code from my github

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I'm working on building a website in Go, which is hosted on my home server via docker.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I make changes to my website/server locally, then push them to github. I'd like to write a dockerfile such that it pulls this data from my github, builds the image, which my docker-compose file will then use to create the container.

Unfortunately, all of my attempts have been somewhat close but wrong.

```
FROM golang:1.8-onbuild
MAINTAINER <my info>
RUN go get <my github url>
ENV webserver_path /website/
ENV PATH $PATH: webserver_path
COPY website/ .
RUN go build .
ENTRYPOINT ./website
EXPOSE <ports>
```

This file is kind of a combination of a few small guides I found through google searches, but none quite gave me the information I needed and it never quite worked.

I'm hoping somebody with decent docker experience can just put a Dockerfile together for me to use as a guide so I can find what I'm doing wrong? I think what I'm looking for can be done in only a few lines, and mine is a little more verbose than needed.

**ADDITIONAL BUT PROBABLY UNNECESSARY INFORMATION BELOW**

Project layout:

[image]

**Data**: is where my go files are Sidenote: This was throwing me errors when trying to build image, something about not being in the environment path. Not sure if that is helpful

**Static**: CSS, JS, Images

**TPL**: go template files

**Main.go**: launches server/website

Comment: But you have two basic approaches available: 1) Have your Dockerfile clone your git repo the same way you would out of docker (i.e. `git clone ...`).  2) Have a build script in your git repo that builds the docker image for you, and pushes it to your Docker repo (i.e. Dockerhub).

Comment: What specific problems are you having building your Docker image? What error do you get? Or what problem do you have with the produced image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github supports [Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) which can be used to do all sorts of things automagically when you push to a git repo. Since you're already running a web server on your home box, why don't you have Github send a POST request to that when it receives a commit on `master` and have your home box re-download the git repo and restart web services from that?

Comment: Although you got downvoted, and this isn't really related to my question, this is actually a super useful suggestion and I will for sure be looking at that. Thank you.

Comment: I actually ended up just doing what you suggested and it was a lot easier than what I think I was trying to do. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There are several strategies:

- **Using of pre-build app**. Build your app using 
  `go build` command according to target system architecture and OS (using GOOS and GOARCH system variable for example) then use COPY docker command to move this builded file (with assets and templates) to your WORKDIR and finally run it via CMD or ENTRYPOINT (last is preferable). Dockerfile for this example will look like:

> FROM scratch
>
> ENV PORT 8000 EXPOSE $PORT
>
> COPY advent / CMD ["/advent"]

- **Build by dockerfile**. Typical Dockerfile:

> ```
> # Start from a Debian image with the latest version of Go installed
> # and a workspace (GOPATH) configured at /go.
> FROM golang
>
> # Copy the local package files to the container's workspace.
> ADD . /go/src/github.com/golang/example/outyet
>
> # Build the outyet command inside the container.
> # (You may fetch or manage dependencies here,
> # either manually or with a tool like "godep".)
> RUN go install github.com/golang/example/outyet
>
> # Run the outyet command by default when the container starts.
> ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/outyet
>
> # Document that the service listens on port 8080.
> EXPOSE 8080
> ```

- **Using GitHub**. Build your app and pull to dockerhub as ready to use image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because this project is a work in progress, I think I want the second method since changes will be made often. Does this method work if the entire project is contained within that "website" directory? All of the code that is needed to run will pull from my GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by just creating an automated build through docker hub, and just using this for my dockerfile:

```
FROM golang-onbuild
EXPOSE <ports>
```

It isn't exactly the correct answer to my question, but it is an effective workaround. The automated build connects with my github repo the way I was hoping my dockerfile would.